# Assistance with "Missing right parenthesis" error

Tags: sql, oracle

The following statement fails with an error "missing right parenthesis":

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
     ( Student# NUMBER(9),
       FirstName VARCHAR2(52),
       LastName VARCHAR2(50),
       DeptID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL, 
       ProjectID NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
       PCID NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
       PR# NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
       Email VARCHAR(50)
      CONSTRAINT student_student#_pk PRIMARY KEY (student#),
       CONSTRAINT student_deptid_fk FOREIGN KEY (deptid)
             REFERENCES department (deptid),
       CONSTRAINT student_pcid_fk FOREIGN KEY (pcid)
             REFERENCES projectcourse (pcid) ,
       CONSTRAINT student_project#_fk FOREIGN KEY (project#)
             REFERENCES project (project#),
       CONSTRAINT student_pr#_fk FOREIGN KEY (pr#)
             REFRENCES projectregisteration (pr#));
```

### EDITED

After a few corrections I'm still getting the `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` error. Below is what my code currently looks like. Any further suggestions will be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
     ( Student# NUMBER(9),
       FirstName VARCHAR2(52),
       LastName VARCHAR2(50),
       DeptID NUMBER(9) NOT NULL, 
       Project# NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
       PCID NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
       PR# NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
       Email VARCHAR2(150),
      CONSTRAINT student_student#_pk PRIMARY KEY (student#),
       CONSTRAINT student_deptid_fk FOREIGN KEY (deptid)
             REFERENCES department (deptid),
       CONSTRAINT student_pcid_fk FOREIGN KEY (pcid)
             REFERENCES projectcourse (pcid) ,
       CONSTRAINT student_project#_fk FOREIGN KEY (project#)
             REFERENCES project (project#),
       CONSTRAINT student_pr#_fk FOREIGN KEY (pr#)
             REFERENCES projectregisteration (pr#));
```

Comment: You may want to avoid using `VARCHAR` in Oracle (`Email VARCHAR(50)`) - I would recommend (and Oracle recommends) using `VARCHAR2` instead. At the moment their behavior is the same but that could change in the future. Also, 50 characters is pretty small for an email address.

Answer (score 2):

A `,` is missing after `Email VARCHAR(50)`. There's a typo, `REFRENCES` instead of `REFERENCES`. And in `CONSTRAINT student_project#_fk FOREIGN KEY (project#)`, the column `project#` isn't in the list of columns above.

Comment: To add to this, although # (and $) are technically allowed in column names, they shouldn't be used as they can cause unexpected issues. Column names should only include letters, numbers, and underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle compiler throws *missing right parenthesis* when we have made a syntax error in our code.

Obviously the first thing to check is that we have a right parenthesis for every left parenthesis; this is easy if we're using an editing tool which supports bracket matching (say by highlighting matching pairs).

But often we have matched all the brackets, so why do we get this error? It happens when we have missed something, and the compiler interprets that as a missing bracket.

For instance a valid CREATE TABLE statement consists of a number of clauses defining columns and constraints, enclosed by a pair of brackets (optionally followed by a storage clause). The important things is that the column and constraint clauses are all separated by commas. In your statement you have missed the comma after the `Email VARCHAR(50)`. The compiler interprets this as the end of the statement and expects a right parenthesis. But your statement kicks off a constraint clause instead. Hence the error message.

It would be neat if the compiler was clever enough to identify a missing comma, but that would require the compiler to additional work and the compiler writers opted to outsource that work to us instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your last foreign key constraint, you have the table name entered as "projectregisteration". Are you certain that's correct? Please check that the table name is as you've typed it, and *not* "projectregistration" (without the "e" after the first "t" in "registration").

If I create all the tables as shown in your second CREATE TABLE statement, then the statement executes without a problem. However, if I make the last table `PROJECTREGISTRATION` (correct spelling of "registration") instead of `PROJECTREGISTERATION` (as shown in your CREATE TABLE) then the CREATE TABLE fails with `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`, just as you stated.

So I suspect it's a simple typo.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=426f0f1f4c9629e46aae524fb5cfa7a8)

Best of luck.